# Primefaces 3.1 Overlay panel misfunctioning on IE8

Tags: primefaces, overlay

This question was previously posted on Primefaces forum where I din't receive any answer.

I'm trying Primefaces 3.1 because I would need the overlay panel functionality.
Unfortunately in my Internet explorer 8 (ie8) the following very simple overlay panel is never displayed, while it works quite fine on Firefox 5.x.
Some points in the html code which seem directly related to the Ie8 problem are the following:
- the page doesn't need a vertical scrollabar (if the page has one the overlay panel is shown)
- the overlayPanel height is fixed.

```
<h:body>
<div style="height: 300px"></div>
<h:form>
<p:commandLink id="showAllUserList" value="Utenti online" />
<p:overlayPanel for="showAllUserList" my="right bottom" at="right top" dynamic="true"
style="width: 300px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid red; overflow-y: scroll" >
He who rules the skies rules the ground
<br/>
Monti kicks ass
</p:overlayPanel>
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

If I don't find a workaround soon I would have to implement something myself.

Thanks
Filippo

Answer (score 1):

Put the following Javascript code **before** closing the **h:body** Tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if ( $.browser.msie) {
   if(parseInt($.browser.version, 10) === 8){
      var overlayPan = $("div.ui-overlaypanel");
      $(overlayPan).css('position','fixed');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting `appendToBody` to `true` for the overlay panel. This can help in some situations, though to be honest I think your page is simple enough that it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Currently I am having the same problem with IE8 - When the Overlay should appear (mouseover effect) my page gets a scrollbar. If I change the size of my browser window the overlay is displayed...

Answer (score 0):

Check your styles for `overflow:hidden` (also of the child elements of `.ui-overlaypanel`), play around giving them `overflow:visible` - in combination with a fixed size (as you already have) I was able to solve the problem.